# Read Gridview exact rows after adding a dynamically added header?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a table header row dynamically as shown below. It is rendered correctly.
So now I have 2 headers.

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

{

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    GridViewRow newHeaderRow = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

    TableCell cell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
    cell1.ColumnSpan = 1; //e.Row.Cells.Count;
    cell1.Text = "Expected";

    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
    cell2.ColumnSpan = 2;
    cell2.Text = "One";

    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
    cell3.ColumnSpan = 2;
    cell3.Text = "Two";

    TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
    cell4.ColumnSpan = 2;
    cell4.Text = "Three";

    newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
    newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell2);
    newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell3);
    newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell4);

    ((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, newHeaderRow);
}
```

}

If my gridview is having 3 rows, and loop through gridview it will read only 2 row.
It is skiping the last row.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. write this code on RowCreated event.
I wrote this code on RowDataBound so created header row was not consistent.

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    GridViewRow newHeaderRow = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

```
TableCell cell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
cell1.ColumnSpan = 1; //e.Row.Cells.Count;
cell1.Text = "Expected";

TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
cell2.ColumnSpan = 2;
cell2.Text = "One";

TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
cell3.ColumnSpan = 2;
cell3.Text = "Two";

TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
cell4.ColumnSpan = 2;
cell4.Text = "Three";

newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell2);
newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell3);
newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell4);

((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, newHeaderRow);
```

}